# android switching one fragment for another

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

edit: still haven't figure this out

Okay, so I have 2 fragments. The first fragment (fragment_main) is a every "page" of a ViewPager of 3 fragments. There is one button on fragment_main, and I want it so that when I click this button, I replace the ViewPager's fragment (fragment_main), with a new fragment (fragment2). Here's my main Activity:

```
package com.example.wyatt.listtest;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            case 1:
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            case 2:
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Button b;

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonNew);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //I would like to switch fragment_main
               //for fragment 2 when this is clicked
           }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}

public static class ReplacementFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static ReplacementFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        ReplacementFragment fragment = new ReplacementFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public ReplacementFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

here's the xml for mainActivity:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:textColor="#000" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

here's fragment_main xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="test" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="new fragment"
    android:id="@+id/buttonNew"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

here is fragment2 xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<!-- This should be EditText, not EditTexta -->
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:text="done"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to swap out fragments from the main fragment (which uses a viewpager), then you can just call the Activitiy's support fragment manager and swap the fragments.

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Adding 1 as the default value for new instance of ReplacementFragment 
            //because I'm not sure what it's purpose is from your code's static constructor.
            ReplacementFragment frag = ReplacementFragment.newInstance(1);
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container, frag);
            ft.commit();
       }
    });
```

Also, R.id.container is in reference to a FrameLayout that contains the ViewPager / ReplaceFragment when you swap back and forth. Create this by modifying your main xml file:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</FrameLayout>
```

As you can see, we are using the FrameLayout as a container for your desired fragments for your main Activity. Initially, you use it for holding the ViewPager with it's three sliding screens, and upon button click you use the fragment manager from your activity to replace the fragment that is lives in your FrameLayout container.

***Note: Depending on if you are using these imports:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

You will get a crash using SupportFragmentManager, instead you FragmentManager, or just switch the imports to above.

---

Comment: I just get a crash with this:  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class EditTexta
at com.example.wyatt.listtest.MainActivity$ReplacementFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:199) which is : View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false); in the replacementfragment

Comment: Can't see what you pasted, could you put it in pastebin and send a link? And/or read my above edit to my answer to see if it solves your crashing issue.

Comment: Oh I see, change your EditTexta to EditText in fragment2 xml:

Comment: maybe that was a typo in your question, but it will crash you as is with how you have it in the question's layout

Comment: alright, it works now, but this is not what I want to do. it lays the new fragment over everything else, including on top the pagertitlestrip. I want it to replace the contents of the current section of pagertitlestrip.

Comment: Do you want to be able to swipe to this fragment always, or just when the user clicks the button? In which case do you also want the pagertitlestrip to display a specific title item? I can help you do this, and modify my answer to do so.

Comment: Yes, I would like to swipe always. I want to click the button, have it change, then be able to swipe to other "tabs" and when i go back to the "tab" i clicked the button on, it to still be changed.

Comment: So you want to add a tab when the button is pressed? Which then stays around in the ViewPager from the moment your pressed the button on? in which case I can help you do this. Just trying to be clear before I continue trying to help :)

Comment: no, I don't want to add a tab, I want it to replace the tab with the button. I just want the change to remain even after I swipe to a different tab and come back.

Comment: You need to replace fragments from your top activity but not from the fragment which will be replaced ...

Comment: could you please elaborate?